# Is Alkanol an official part of chemical Nomenclature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols

There are several references to alkanols [here](http://elchem.kaist.ac.kr/jhkwak/okanaganpdb97/nomenclature/ane-720.htm) and [here](http://www.easychem.com.au/the-acidic-environment/esterification/alkanols-and-alkanoic-acids) but neither of these sources are too reliable. The IUPAC gold book seems [not to recognise the term](http://goldbook.iupac.org/search.py?search_text=alkanol) and a quick [google search](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=alkanols) reveals no really good sources.Whilst still not a super reliable source the fact there are no results on Wikipedia but simply a redirect to alcohol also furthers concerns and so the question is: Is the term Alkanol a 'real', 'proper', and 'official' term in chemistry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUPAC gold book doesn't recognize it, that's a pretty solid answer. I've never heard anyone say 'alkanol' before either, I've only heard people refer to these as simply alcohols. However, there are people who still use the word 'ethylene' to describe the compound 'ethene' so it could just happen to be some common language I haven't been exposed to.

To be clear, no it's not official, but yes it might be real terminology used by some organic chemists.

Answer (score 2):

The term ‘alkanol’ is widely used in the literature; for example, a search on [ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleListURL&_method=list&_ArticleListID=-855244681&_sort=r&_st=13&view=c&md5=02517da70d66742aaf19cc7d8f8b82b4&searchtype=a) yields several thousand results. It is true though that ‘alkanol’ is not included in the systematic IUPAC nomenclature.

You are right that the [IUPAC *Compendium of Chemical Terminology* (Gold Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook), Version 2.3.3 (2014-02-24) does not include the word ‘alkanol’. However, the Gold Book is merely a collection of terminology definitions found in other IUPAC publications. It is not a sufficient source for nomenclature rules. Nevertheless, class names of organic compounds are usually included in the Gold Book.

The current rules for nomenclature of organic chemistry can be found in [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013* (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001). In many cases, the Blue Book uses the class names of organic compound given in the [*Glossary of class names of organic compounds and reactivity intermediates based on structure (IUPAC Recommendations 1995)*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307). Neither of them includes the word ‘alkanol’.

According to current IUPAC recommendations, the class name for compounds in which a hydroxy group $\ce{-OH}$ is attached to a saturated carbon atom is ‘alcohols’.

Alcohols can be named in several ways. Preferred IUPAC names of simple alcohols are generated by attaching the suffix ‘ol’ to the name of the parent hydride, with elision of the final letter ‘e’ in the parent hydride, if present (methanol, ethanol, propan-1-ol, etc.).

In general nomenclature it is also possible (and particularly relevant in the older literature) to generate the name by linking a substituent groups (a radical) to the class name ‘alcohol’ (methyl alcohol, ethyl alcohol, propyl alcohol, etc.).

Since ‘alkyl group’ is a valid class name, it is in principle possible to use the historical rule and generate the generic name ‘alkyl alcohol’. The term ‘alkanol’ might be considered the analogous generic name in imitation of the currently preferred method using the suffix ‘ol’:

methyl alcohol → methanol
ethyl alcohol → ethanol
alkyl alcohol → alkanol

However, such analogies can be deceptive. The analogous conversion of the (not preferred but correct) name ‘isopropyl alcohol’ would yield the incorrect name ‘isopropanol’. (IUPAC recommends that the name ‘isopropanol’ should be abandoned since there is no hydrocarbon ‘isopropane’).

Answer (score 0):

If it is not given in the Gold Book, then it is not an official part of nomenclature.

However, at the same time the equation alkanol = simple alcohol is incorrect. Alkanol would be used only for completely saturated alcohol, while for exaple allylic alcohol (prop-2-en-1-ol) or but-2-en-1,4-diol are clearly very simple alcohols but *not* alkanols.

Much like alkanol also similar terms as *alkenol, alkanone, alkenone* etc. are in use.

You can expect every organic chemist to understand the term correctly after about two semesters’ organic chemistry courses.